# Memory Pool Returned Memory Alignment

Tags: c++11, gcc, memory-management, arm, x86-64

In my application I have a memory pool. I allocate all memory at startup in the form of a `uint64` array (64 bit machine). Then construct objects in this array using placement new. So object 1 starts at position `pool[0]` object 2 start at position `pool[1]` so on so forth. Since each object will span at least 64bits or multiples of `sizeof(uint64)` (if it needs more `uint64` slots to allocate).

Am I correct to assume that all memory returned from the pool will be aligned correctly? Since each `uint64` in the array will be properly aligned by the compiler. If so, does using `uint32` on a 32bit machine in the same manner will work?

Comment: This very much depends on the compiler and the memory allocator you use. What are you using? This cannot be answered globally for all C++ programs.

Comment: @LiranFunaro my target compilers are gcc and clang. no allocator is involved memory is a global array of uint64 s

Comment: Any specific architecture?

Comment: @LiranFunaro currently x86_64 but the reason I asked for 32 bit is I will also be running on 32 bit arm.

Comment: I hope you mean position 0 not position 1.  With position 1 you'll still get 64-bit alignment assuming that your array is properly aligned, but you might not get page or cache line alignment, both of which seem undesirable.

Comment: @SamHartman You are right it was a typo objects start at position 0. That was what I meant to write but in reality with an empty pool pool[0] contains the allocation size and the actual object starts at pool[1] + n. n being the how many pages the object requires.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to assume that there will not be any padding. Compilers mostly pack in 2 bytes or 4 bytes boundaries (this can be controlled).
You should verify this on your specific target using [`__alignof__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Alignment.html).

> The keyword `__alignof__` allows you to inquire about how an object is aligned, or the minimum alignment usually required by a type. Its syntax is just like sizeof.

However, an allocation of 8 bytes, might not be aligned to 64bit, if the array was allocated starting with a 32bit offset address.

You could use [`aligned_alloc(8, size)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) to allocate the memory, then cast it to array of `uint64`.